# Cannot use Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2012 within VS2013 Report Designer, always returns blank?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I'm attempting to create a parameterized report within a C# application. When I go to the Data Source Designer, I can select preview, and see the appropriate data just fine. However, when I attempt to create a report with the stored procedure, the report ends up being blank, as if no rows are returned

If I create a brand new report, without the parameters, it still returns blank. However, my views and tables pull just fine.

Any ideas?

EDIT

Code Attempt 1

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getReportData] 
@minimumDate DATE = '1900-01-01', 
@maximumDate DATE = '2100-12-31',
@PO INT = null,
@glCode INT = null,
@merchant INT = null,
@employee INT = null
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT  dbo.transactions.date_purchased, 
        dbo.transactions.description, 
        dbo.transactions.purchase_order_number, 
        dbo.transaction_codes.transaction_code, 
        dbo.merchants.merchant, 
        dbo.transactions.amount, 
        dbo.employees.first_name + ' ' + dbo.employees.last_name AS employee
FROM    dbo.transactions 
      INNER JOIN dbo.transaction_codes ON dbo.transactions.accounting_code = dbo.transaction_codes.id    
      INNER JOIN dbo.merchants ON dbo.transactions.merchant_id = dbo.merchants.id 
      INNER JOIN dbo.employees ON dbo.transactions.employee_id = dbo.employees.id
WHERE   
        (dbo.transactions.date_purchased BETWEEN @minimumDate AND @maximumDate) AND
        (@employee IS NULL or dbo.transactions.employee_id IN(@employee)) AND
        (@po is null or dbo.transactions.purchase_order_number = @PO) AND (@merchant is null or dbo.transactions.merchant_id IN(@merchant)) AND
        (@glCode is null or dbo.transactions.accounting_code IN(@glCode))




END
```

Without parameters

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getData
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT  dbo.transactions.date_purchased, 
        dbo.transactions.description, 
        dbo.transactions.purchase_order_number, 
        dbo.transaction_codes.transaction_code, 
        dbo.merchants.merchant, 
        dbo.transactions.amount, 
        dbo.employees.first_name + ' ' + dbo.employees.last_name AS employee
FROM    dbo.transactions INNER JOIN
        dbo.transaction_codes ON dbo.transactions.accounting_code = dbo.transaction_codes.id INNER JOIN
        dbo.merchants ON dbo.transactions.merchant_id = dbo.merchants.id INNER JOIN
        dbo.employees ON dbo.transactions.employee_id = dbo.employees.id
END
GO
```

Comment: can you show the stored procedure and code behind if any that you are using..?

Comment: I've updated it with the two different stored procedures I've attempted.

Comment: few questions ..why you are hard coding these 2 lines `@minimumDate DATE = '1900-01-01', 
@maximumDate DATE = '2100-12-31',` are you familiar with `GetDate()` method also have you run this query in query analyzer

Comment: I have not ran it in query analyzer, but when I run the stored procedure from within SMMS it works just fine. Also, they are hard coded as default values for simplicity. In the event that we have future dated purchases, I essentially want the entire date range available.

Comment: sounds like this is an issue with the way you are assigning the DataSource and or connecting to the Reports Designer itself..

Comment: I'm not quite sure why, as it seems to work perfectly fine with every other table.

Comment: well this is where you may have to check  the settings against all the working tables you are probably overlooking something but we can't tell from here only other thing I can think of is the `Alias` Field name is it being mapped as the `Alias` name or the Table `FieldName` in the reports this is the only other thing I can think of

Comment: I actually just tried the second stored procedure again, and it worked fine. Now it's just the first one that refuses to work.

Comment: try to break it down I think that where you are checking this line it also looks rather odd `or dbo.transactions.employee_id IN(@employee` where you are using the `IN Clause` what happens if you have Null values. .try replacing those @variables with hard coded values that you know exist.. and see what happens..

Comment: If I right click on the data source within VS2013, and hit preview. Everything works great. I can then put in different values, and again it filters it correctly. It simply will not work from within the report itself.

Comment: How are you adding the SP to the report. I remember when you add a SP, it prompts for Parameters, DO NOT leave any parameters empty, give some defaults. These defaults will be overriden at runtime anyway.

Comment: I simple use the wizard. And select it from my Data Source

Answer (score -2):

Next thing I would try is a report with an embedded query to see if data is returned. Perhaps, nothing will be returned but something might click for you along the way.